# Firebase analytics android apps

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-analytics

When implementing fire base analytics in android apps do i need to add any codes in the app side or is it enough to enable it in firebase console only. Does it same in ios

Answer (score 0):

You should add Firebase SDK to your app. see this link:
[Firebase android setup page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

For ios you should add Firebase configuration file to your project, then add Firebase SDK to the app and then you should initialize it. detailed instructions can be found here:
[Firebase ios setup page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

Answer (score 0):

if you just need normal analytics like number of installs, uninstalls, cache clear etc, 
but if you want specific analytics like number of users visited a specific page you will have to create a event in firebase and write code for that event.